# How do I use idToken with Firebase in Android

Tags: android, firebase, http, firebase-authentication

I'm making an Android app that will be using a REST API that I'm building in Firebase Functions and I have a question regarding user authentication.

As far as I've gathered, I have to send the user's idToken to the API with every HTTP call, to verify that the user is logged in and can access the API resource. So far so good.

I'm following this guide for sending the idToken:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens

What confuses me is that with that piece of code, it seems that I have to build all my code within the "if (task.isSuccessful())" part to be able to use the idToken, since I can't return any values from that inner class, to be used elsewhere in the app.

Isn't that impractical, since it would mean that I have to fetch the idToken every time I want to make an HTTP call, instead of reusing the one I've already found?

I considered storing the idToken in a cookie, but it seems that cookie would still be "locked" to the inner class, isn't that right?

How do (normal) people normally do this?

```java
FirebaseUser mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
mUser.getIdToken(true)
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                String idToken = task.getResult().getToken();
                // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
                // ...
            } else {
                // Handle error -> task.getException();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two ways to call firebase functions from android app 
1;) as a rest api 
2:) using firebase functions library to call it directly (easier)

currently you are trying to use first option . drawbacks of this way is that you need to send id token with each request and verify it in cloud functions .

if you use 2nd way then you won't have to send idtoken yourself and firebase library will take care of that
check this link to know how to make direct function calls
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

but if you want to keep using first way then you need to save the idtoken in local storage like this

```
public static void setAccessToken(Context context,String val){
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().putString("idToken",val).apply();
}
public static String getAccessToken(Context context){
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString("idToken",null);
}
```

call setAccessToken() within callback once when you login and when you need to call a function you can get the previous stored token with getAccessToken()